# DB2 query, group result and allow different values to be a comma seperated value

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a very straightforward query that returns results which sometimes have all columns but one to be identical, like so:

```
name   |   address   |   item  |   date
---------------------------------------------
Bob      123 East st    A123     07-02-2020
Bob      123 East st    A213     07-02-2020
```

I want to try and make it so that I can essentially group this result but the items would be a comma separated list like so:

```
name   |   address   |   item          |   date
----------------------------------------------------
Bob      123 East st    A123, A213       07-02-2020
```

My query is:

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, ITEM, DATE
FROM ITEM_TABLE
WHERE DATE <= current_date
GROUP BY NAME, ADDRESS, ITEM, DATE
```

Is there a way where I can change this so it still groups by the other columns but separates the items in a single row by comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing [`listagg()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html):

```
select name, address,
       listagg(item, ',') within group (order by item) as items,
       date
from t
group by name, address, date;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! For some reason this seemed to slip by me but I see now that it truly aggregates within a group. Thank you for this